# Associate part of pointer array in Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, derived-types

I was wondering if there is a way to associate each entry of a pointer array one at a time in Fortran.
Let's say I know that I am going to have 5 entries in the pointer array but these entries are defined as the program advances. 
A minimal example in pseudo-code is the following:

```
myData         ! containing data of derived type (vehicle) and specifically: 
               ! 3 cars, 5 bikes, 2 trucks
myptr(:)       ! it is of the correct type vehicle and I know in advance 
               ! that I am going to store 5 objects.
n = 0
do while (n<5)
  ! car loop
  do i=1,3
    if (something is true for car(i)) then
      n = n + 1
      myptr(n) => car(i)
      cycle (do while)
    end if
  end do
  ! bike loop
  do i=1,5
    if (something is true for bike(i)) then
      n = n + 1
      myptr(n) => bike(i)
      cycle (do while)
    end if
  end do
  ! same for truck
end do (while)
```

It seems to be illegal to associate the pointer in this way and in general I understand why. 
I feel that there is a relatively simple workaround but at the moment I am stuck and a bit obsessed to make it work this way... I would be grateful if you have any suggestions or advice on the matter!

Comment: There's no such thing as 'individual' elements of a pointer, really. A pointer has rank equal to the thing it points at. For this task, typically one uses a linked list.

Comment: Fortran doesn't really have arrays of pointers, rather it has pointers to arrays.  You might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092183/fortran-pointers-to-structures/20092892#20092892

Comment: Thank you for your answers! The advice from @Ross was spot on! High Perfromance Mark, I've seen the post but I was looking for a workaround since I was stuck. Thanks again to both of you.

Comment: If you are satisfied I am closing this as a duplicate of the already linked question. There is no simple workaround, Fortran simply does not have anything like arrays of pointers. The usual workaround is in the linked answer.